# How to make a chisq.test() by parameter in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have the following data frame:

> df

```
User    Feature1    Feature2    Num
name1   a           x1          12
name1   a           x2          3
name1   a           x3          7
name1   b           x2          3
name2   a           x2          8
name2   b           x3          7
name2   c           x2          3
```

...

First row exp: user "name1" connected from "a" to "x1" 12 times.

I want to create a table with chisq.test() between M1 to M2 for each user (with consideration to number of connections).

The number of rows in the output table should be equal to the amount of users in the data frame.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the data example is that `chisq.test` returns NA if any column or row sums to 0.

```
by( df[-1], df[[1]], function(d) { 
                tbl <- xtabs(Num ~ Feature1 + Feature2, data=d)
                i <- apply( tbl, 1, sum ) > 0
                j <- apply( tbl, 2, sum ) > 0
                chisq.test( tbl[i,j] )})
#-------- result ----------
df[[1]]: name1

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  tbl[i, j]
X-squared = 10.7955, df = 2, p-value = 0.004527

---------------------------------------------------------------- 
df[[1]]: name2

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  tbl[i, j]
X-squared = 18, df = 2, p-value = 0.0001234
```

Comment: Thanks. The solution suggested works, but it's not exactly what I need. I want each user chisq.test() to be on his features and not on all users features. For exm: user "name1" with feature1: a,b and not c. Do you have an idea?

Comment: I don't see how that is different than what is being done now. If you just want to change the name of the returned values based on the i-j values that are present for a given 'name_x' then have you tried using `setNames`.